# Python 3 Connect to API and create CSV

Tags: json, export-to-csv, python-3.6

I'm a newbie in Python and would really appreciate some tips how to make this work. I'm trying to connect to an API in JSON format and then create a CSV of output. As of now, I think, I have problem reading all values into csv file.

```
import json, requests, sys



# Download the JSON data from SCB's API with specified URL.
url ='http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/BE/BE0101/BE0101A/BefolkningNy'
# Store URL and pass it to request.get to get a response object  
response = requests.get(url)
# For Response object I can check for errors with raise_for_status function 
response.raise_for_status()

# Then I load JSON data into a Python variable.
scbdata = json.loads(response.text)
print(scbdata)

#if I understand this correctly I'm now having python dictionary?

# then I would like to read this to csv
import csv





# function to open scb.csv and will close automatic?
csvWriter = csv.writer(open("\Users\name\Desktop\Python\Json\scb.csv", 'w'), delimiter=',', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

#first write column headers 
csvWriter.writerow(list(scbdata.keys())

#Now I need to loop values into csv but not sure how?
for i in range(len(scbdata['?????'])):
    csvWriter.writerow([scbdata[k][i] for k in scbdata.keys()])
```

####### Wanted Output format from URL

region       Gender Age          Year   Values

01 Stockholms län   male        16-19   2000    26.1
                   01 Stockholms län    male        16-19   2001    26.2
  01 Stockholms län male        16-19   2002    23.7

Comment: A little more information would be helpful - depending on where the failure occurs: 1 - sample JSON data, 2 - results of `print(scbdata)`, 3 - data stored in the CSV file (i.e., full text of file).

Comment: I had a look at the API data and the data isn't formatted in a way that the values for each CSV line is obvious. Please update your question with how you are looking to transform the data.

Comment: thx for feedback manassehkatz and Milk. After reading more about python objects and JSON i understand that scbdata only provides me meta-data of different nested dict and lists. To get actual values I need to post my JSON query to url. If it's possible best scenario would be request url and then get all values with all possible dimensions in a structured way with just one JSON query, is that possible?